# "'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton intValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" between initwithNibName: and viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a fairly simple app (my first non-trivial iOS app) which I've been working on for some time. I've gotten the app finished and working, but I decided earlier today to refactor it to better fit OO design principles (in the interest of simplicity I had put most of my application in to the main view controller; I went back to try to split it out in to a second class). Now, whenever I try to run my app, I get a crash with the following error before my main view loads:

```
IntervalPlayer[1374:907] -[UIButton intValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c5569d0
```

By throwing print statements everywhere, I can tell that I get through initWithNibName:bundle: OK, but the app crashes before viewDidLoad is called. Clearly something in my code is trying to call intValue on a UIButton, but there's nothing in my code that would do that - I only use intValue once in the entire app, and I get the same error when I comment that line out. In fact, I've tried commenting out everything in initWithNibName:bundle: after the call to the superclass constructor, and I'm getting the same error at the same place. So in other words, as best I can tell, something in an empty constructor is causing intValue to be called on a UIButton before anything else in my app has a chance to run. I assume its something in the delegate or nib, but I've looked through both and I haven't seen anything out-of-the-ordinary. Has anyone out there ever run in to something like this?

Forgive the lack of code snippets, I'm not sure what I would provide to illustrate this. Here's the empty constructor, with which the error is still occurring:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)aBundle
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)aBundle];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
 }
```

If anyone can suggest any other code to add, I'll edit the question to do so.

Thanks,

Dan

EDIT: Yes, I am using ARC. Also, to clarify, this is occurring in my main view controller and I haven't touched the delegate.

EDIT 2: The crash is in my delegate; according to the debugger the problem line is [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; Since I haven't touched the delegate, my guess would be the NIB is somehow invalid.

FINAL EDIT: By deleting buttons until I found the one causing the crash, then hooking it back up to everything it was hooked up to in the view controller, I found that it was crashing when the button was connected to a UIButton outlet, and not crashing when it wasn't. I removed the outlet, re-made it, and now it works. So I have no clue what happened, but somehow I fixed it. Many thanks to everyone who made suggestions!

Comment: Are you using ARC?  Such errors tend to occur when an object released from memory is then accessed.  For example, there is an object such as a NSString, that you could call intValue on being released.  Then a UIButton is created at it's old location.  When someone attempts to call intValue on the released NSString, they get the UIButton instead, causing the exception.

Comment: aepryus: I had thought something like that, but since the issue occurs after an empty constructor runs but before anything else is created or   used, I'm not sure what else could have been created and then released before the button is made.

Comment: Check that all outlet connections in the view are ok.

Comment: That might be a good idea to check if the nib is valid, check `loadView` (override it with only calling [super loadView] if needed) to be completed.

Comment: @DanielGiovannelli: Unless this is the only class in your program, a lot of other stuff could have been created and released.

Comment: @Chuck, I should have been clearer: this is my main view controller, so it should be the first thing that loads AFAIK, since I haven't touched the delegate at all. Everyone else, I'm away from my computer right now but I'll double-check the nib and load view ASAP. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turn on breakpoints in your app so XCode will show you the line that the error happens on.

1. Open the Breakpoint Navigator
2. Tap the + button in the bottom left and add an Exception Breakpoint
3. Just hit done
4. Run your app, it'll stop at the line of code that's causing the issue.

Post the line of code that's causing the crash here if you're having trouble with it

Comment: The crash is in my delegate; according to the debugger the problem line is [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; Since I haven't touched the delegate, my guess would be the NIB is somehow invalid. I'll look in to that.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this same exact error and symptoms.  Recreating the button and redoing the outlet didn't help.  I wasn't making a mistake with the IB connections, though.

What I had absentmindedly done was name the button's outlet `tag` and this aliased the NSInteger property of the same name that all UIViews have.  When loading my NIB, iOS was somewhere essentially doing `[tag getInt]`, but using my button instead of the NSInteger property it wanted.